# I would like to theme an attachment display differently if there are no results for the parent display

Tags: views, theming

I have a view attachment that displays featured content. It's attached to a block that shows non-featured content. Which template should I use to theme the attachment in case there are no results for the block? If I theme the attachment, I'm not able to access anything I could use from the block for a conditional statement.